# How do I change the format of a datetime object to a specified format?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I'm trying to make this date more readable can someone please help me...

So Right now my current code is:

```
embed.add_field(name="Joined at:", value = str(member.joined_at), inline=False)
```

And when I run this code in discord I get this:
[image: 1]

But I want to get something that looks like: [image]

As you can see it is a lot easier to read and understand.

Could someone please help me?!

Thanks-

Comment: What's wrong with the first thing? It's in UTC and 24-hour time, but other than that it conveys the exact same info.

Comment: yes, but im trying to make the first one 24 hour time and not UTC!

Comment: Have you checked the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`strftime()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`timestamp`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.timestamp) arg.

```
embed=discord.Embed(title='Joined at:', timestamp=member.joined_at)
```

This will show the time reletive to the displaying device's timezone

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your value to the following format:

```
value = datetime.date.strftime(member.joined_at, '%a, %b %d, %Y, %I %p')
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thank you so muchhh!